# When are tag wikis created by the Community user vs a normal user?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki, community-user

When viewing the history of tag wikis, I've come across quite a few tags showing that the original revision was by the Community user, and quite a few that were by normal users. Two random examples I've come across are [languages](/questions/tagged/languages) and [profile-picture](/questions/tagged/profile-picture). When viewing the tag wiki histories, you can see that [profile-picture](/questions/tagged/profile-picture) was originally created by Community, and [languages](/questions/tagged/languages) was originally created by a normal user.

[image]

[image]

I've also found that, when going to `Activity -> All Actions -> Posts` in a user's profile, there's a certain type of post called `wiki`, which seems to be the creation of a tag wiki. You can see this in [the Community user's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=posts).

I never see an option to create a tag wiki when I'm creating a tag, though that might be because I don't have tag wiki edit privileges.

When are tag wikis shown as being created by normal users vs the community user?

Comment: They were probably created by users who were later deleted, and ownership transferred to Community.  I don't know why questions and answers from deleted users are treated one way and tag wikis another, which is why I didn't write an answer -- my guess might be wrong.  But it's a starting point if you want to do some digging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342232/4284627), it depends on whether the first revision of the tag wiki had to go through review or not, that is if the user who wrote it had the privilege to edit tag wikis without review. If the user could edit the tag wiki without review, that user is marked as the creator of the tag wiki, otherwise the Community user is marked as the creator of the tag wiki.

> They [the tag wikis] are credited to the first *editor* of the wiki. If you haven't yet got the [trusted user privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) and must suggest a tag wiki edit instead, then the first editor is the Community user, creating an empty placeholder stub the moment a suggested edit is created (so before review has completed, regardless of wether or not that edit is accepted).

In your example ([profile-picture](/questions/tagged/profile-picture)), it looks like a user without the privilege to edit tag wikis suggested a tag wiki which got rejected, and about 6 months later a moderator wrote another tag wiki which didn't have to go through review.